# Interactive shapes with text on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shapes

so I am tasked to do a project. So let me show something first. [image]

In this one. The Purple shape should only appear when Durable Returns part is clicked.

Now I am drawing blanks with coming up ideas on how to do this. What I want to ask is if it's possible to recreate all of this in html interactively.

Comment: if we consider the tags you added, for sure this can be done .. I am pretty sure you saw more complex than this, no?

Comment: Why is anyone downvoting this question?  It's clear and concise, with a specific problem, and enough information provided.

Comment: @Brad maybe because it's opinion based ... best approach = opinion

Comment: @TemaniAfif For anyone who actually reads the question, they'll see it's not opinion-based at all.  There are only two ways to do this (SVG and Canvas) and Canvas is outright the wrong answer.

Comment: @Brad sorry but I don't agree there is only 2 ways :) .. we can also do this with pure CSS/HTML if we want . with canvas, with SVG, with JS libraries that rely on this, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, sure, good luck with your CSS hacks to make such a pie chart while still retaining a reasonable markup and browser compatibility.  That's even more unworkable than canvas.  Post that as an answer if that's what you truly believe the solution is.

Comment: @Brad it was *my* opinion and *you* don't agree which make this question opinion based for *me* :)  But it's only me, at least I gave a reason to my downvote and close vote for the quesion.

Comment: Every question has some level of opinion.  That's the whole point of voting.  It's wrong to say that this question was purely stepping into the realm of opinion-based.  I fixed the title.

Comment: @Selim Just an FYI, your question at it's core is fine.  Leave it to a bunch of pendantic engineers (speaking mainly of people who *didn't* post their reasoning) to downvote a question because they didn't read.  I do recommend that in your future questions, be more specific in what you're asking and be very clear about it so that those who skim by and vote down will have less of a reason to do so.  And, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is what you actually want.

SVG has a DOM with different elements, allowing you to have polygons and such that you can place arbitrarily.  You can embed text and lay it out as you need as well.  SVG in-browser can be scripted and also have CSS applied to it.

Comment: i figured i need to read about svg. my initial approach was to just find some js scripts for shapes but i guess it would take more than that. thank you for this. will select this as an answer after 12 minutes

Comment: i was not the one who did that. i upvoted it then it became 0.

Comment: @Selim you can find JS script, but this doesn't mean that you won't use SVG .. the JS will for sure rely on SVG or something else like canvas